# multiple clients - one server connection with sockets tcp/ip c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, client

I need to develop a client server system where I can have multiple clients communicating with one server at the same time. I want to communicate xml serialized objects and also need to send and receive other commands to invoke methods. Now, I am just starting with socket programming in C# and .Net and found that the asynchronous I/O is the way to go so that the methods dont block the execution of code. Also there are many examples of how to

make a simple client server system. So I have a basic understanding of how that works.

Anyway, what still is not clear to me is how I can set up a server which can manage connections to multiple clients? 
Can I just create a new socket per connection and then store those in some kind of list?
Do I need some kind of multiplexing to achieve this? 
Do I have to listen at multiple ports?
What`s the best way here?

And the other thing is if I need to develop my own protocol to differentiate between what I am actually sending over the network --> xml serialized object or a command which might be just a string encoded in ascII or something. Or would I develop my own protocol just to send these commands?

Any kind of help is apreciated! If someone knows a good book which covers this sort of stuff, let me know. Cheers

I forgot to mention that some of my clients which are supposed to communicate with my server will be pda and I therefore use the compact framework... So this might bring in some restrictions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find several of my TCP/IP .NET FAQ entries helpful, particularly [using a socket as a server socket](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/05/using-socket-as-server-listening-socket.html), which explains how listening servers create new client connections, and [XML over TCP/IP](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/07/xml-over-tcpip.html), which discusses the decisions you have to make for an XML-over-TCP/IP protocol.

Comment: Just read the link u posted above. That really was useful. What I did not get is what do you mean by local port? Lets say I am listening at port 8221 for any IP Adress. How can I then create a new socket which would handle the incoming connection with the local port? Would the client then also have to change the port, or how does that work? 

Thanks alot!

Comment: The creation of the new socket bound to an unused local port, and the migration of the client to the new socket, is all handled for you by the TCP/IP stack. So, as far as server code is concerned, you can continue listening on 8221; and as far as client code is concerned, it has successfully connected to 8221 (though it actually communicates to the dynamic port selected by the server's TCP/IP stack).

Comment: What I dont get is, how I my listening 'server socket' can pass on the connection to a newly created socket. 
I would suggest I have a socket and call the BeginAccept like follows:

socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback ( OnClientConnect ),null);

but then in my OnClientConnect callback, how do I pass on this connection to a new socket?

Comment: Sorry! My bad. Didnt see the Accept() method returns a new socket! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would abandon your plan to use Sockets and switch to WCF [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx). It's far more elegant and is designed to do all the things you wanted, in a considerably easier and simpler way than .NET sockets.

If you want a guide of how to use it, there are a set of amazing [Microsoft webcasts](http://www.dasblonde.net/2007/06/24/WCFWebcastSeries.aspx) by Michele Leroux Bustamante that will have you up and running in no time.

Comment: Allright. I will have a look at it. Problem might be that my clients actually are PDAs and therefore are restricted in a few ways as I use the Compact Framework for implementation. Of course the server would not be a PDA. So I might be able to make use of the WCF for implementing the server. 

Thanks for your hint!

Comment: Now I found out that the WCF also is available in the compact framework. Would it be possible with WCF to pull data from the client as well?

Comment: Absolutely. You can set up a two-way WCF using callbacks, so the server can call a method on the client (which can have a return parameter). I used WCF to set up a client/server game that sends lots of information back and forth. It's no problem at all!

Comment: Allright then. This sounds really good. I will check it out. Thanks alot! Maybe you know some kind of tutorial of how to implement a two way WCF using callbacks. That would be great. 

Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: You dont know if the two way communication is possible with a pda in general? Cheers.

Comment: Seems like it does not work with PDAs. According to this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/andrewarnottms/archive/2007/09/13/calling-wcf-services-from-netcf-3-5-using-compact-wcf-and-netcfsvcutil-exe.aspx Callback contracts are not available in the Compact Framework...